# Maximum element on a Tree in haskell?

Tags: haskell, data-structures, tree

Given a Tree :

```
data Tree a = Empty | Node a [Tree a] deriving Show
```

I am trying to get the maximum element so I've tried:

```
maxElem:: (Ord a) => Tree a -> Int
maxElem Empty = error "maxElem on empty Tree"
maxElem (Node a []) = a
maxElem (Node a x ) = maximum [ maxElem h | h<-x]
```

But I get an error and I don't find it.

Comment: Note that from a practical standpoint, you don't have to define `maxElem` yourself; using the `DeriveFoldable` extension, you can simply write `data Tree a = ... deriving (Show, Foldable)`, and then something like `maximum (Node 5 [])` would correctly return 5.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are three potential problems here:

1. if a tree contains one or many `Empty`s, it will error. So a `Node 1 [Node 4 [], Empty, Node 2 [Node 5 []]]`, will raise an error since there is an `Empty` in the tree, and we will eventually call `maxElem` on that `Empty` whereas we can ignore the `Empty` and thus return `5`;
2. you also do not take `a` into account when you calculate the maximum of a `Node` with children, whereas the `a` can be the maximum as well;
3. the result is an `a` as well, not per se an `Int`.

There are in fact two cases here:
 1. the `Empty` tree, that raises an error; and
 2. the maximum of a `Node x cs` is the maximum of `x` and the `maxElem` of the children, *ignoring the `Empty`s*.

So we can write it as:

```
maxElem:: Ord a => Tree a -> a
maxElem Empty = error "maxElem on Empty"
maxElem (Node x cs) = maximum (x : map maxElem [c | c@(Node _ _) <- cs])
```

Or we can write the `map maxElem` in the list comprehension:

```
maxElem:: Ord a => Tree a -> a
maxElem Empty = error "maxElem on Empty"
maxElem (Node x cs) = maximum (x : [maxElem c | c@(Node _ _) <- cs])
```

So the base case is the same, but the case of `Node x cs` calculates the `maximum` of a list with `x` as head, and `map MaxElem` as tail, but not on *all* children, but only the children that match the `Node _ _` pattern. Since this list contains at least one element `x`, `maximum` can *not* error on the empty list, and we calculate only `maxElem` on `Node` instances.